# DRF: "GET Not Allowed", on a generic view set with ListModel mixin

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 viewsets on the same url, one for Create and List the other one for retrieve update and destroy. The Viewset Code is follows

```
class UserViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                  mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                  mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                  viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    """
    retrieves user accounts
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)


class UserCreateViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                        mixins.ListModelMixin,
                        viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    """
    Creates user accounts
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CreateUserSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        email = self.request.query_params.get('email', None)
        phone_no = self.request.query_params.get('phone_no', None)

        if email is not None:
            queryset = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        elif phone_no is not None:
            queryset = User.objects.filter(phone_no=phone_no)
        else:
            queryset = User.objects.all()
        return super(UserCreateViewSet, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This is my url configuration:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserCreateViewSet)
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'advertisement', AdvertisementCreateViewSet)
router.register(r'advertisement', AdvertisementViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-token-auth/', CustomAuthToken.as_view()),
    path('api-token-auth/verify-otp', VerifyTokenView.as_view()),
    path('api-token-auth/verify-email', VerifyEmailView.as_view()),
    path('api/v1/admin/login', LoginAdminUser.as_view()),
    path('api/v1/user/reset-password/', ResetPasswordView.as_view()),
    url('api/v1/user/(?P<id>.+)/changePassword', ChangePasswordView.as_view())
    path('api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    re_path(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('api-root'), permanent=False)),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The advertisement ViewSet does the exact same thing on a different model and it works seemlessly.
But in the UserViewSet it doesn't..I tried comparing the code of both viewsets and they are exactly the same....

Comment: There's some information missing here. Which viewset has the problem? Exactly what URL are you going to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstood how `ViewSets` work. A single `ViewSet` could contain the whole logic you wish for your model. I think there is a collision here when you register the routes which makes one of the `ViewSet` inoperative.

You should merge all your logic in a single `ViewSet`:

```py
class UserViewSet(
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet,
):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        """Return the serializer class given the action"""
        action = self.action
        if self.action == 'create' or self.action == 'list':
            return CreateUserSerializer
        else:
            return UserSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        email = self.request.query_params.get('email', None)
        phone_no = self.request.query_params.get('phone_no', None)

        if email is not None:
            queryset = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        elif phone_no is not None:
            queryset = User.objects.filter(phone_no=phone_no)
        else:
            queryset = User.objects.all()
        return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

A few comments about my example:

- I overrided `get_serializer_class` because I saw you had two different serializers on your viewsets. However, I'm quite sure you can do what you want by using [`read_only`/`write_only` options](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments) of the `Serializer` fields.
- In your `list` view, you are implementing some filtering logic. You can do this more easily with [`django-filter`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend), without having to overload the `list` method.